# Handling Slack Buttons in Botbuilder/nodejs

Tags: node.js, slack, botframework

I am using the nodejs botbuilder framework. A confirm prompt will show yes/no buttons in slack, but they don't do anything when pressed. The slackbot responds with "Hmm, that didn't work, because this app is missing a request URL. Define one here: MIP Bot"

How can I setup my botbuilder app to handle the buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable "Interactive Messages" in the slack developer console by entering this "Request URL"

```
https://slack.botframework.com/api/Actions
```

Then you need to copy your slack "Verification Token" and paste that where it goes in the bot framework slack channel configuration.

My Slack buttons work - yay.